# Concatenate columns in alphabetic order in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery:

```
|c1|c2|c3|
----------
|a1|'b'|c1|
----------
|a1|'a'|c2|
----------
```

and I want to group by c1 and array_agg c2 and have a table like below:

```
 c1| c2
--------
 a1|'ab'
```

which concatenate the c2 column and save the alphabetic order.
can someone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Your question pretty much describes the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following. you can use `order by` inside `string_agg`. here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg).

```
select
    c1,
    string_agg(c2 order by c2) as c2
from yourTable
group by
    c1
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I think, string_agg doesn't save the order?

Comment: @MaryamAbdoli it does, you can use `order by` inside `string_agg`. I have updated my answer.